# Why std::filesystem is not support for Mac qt6.2?

Tags: c++, qt

I'd like to use QFile function `std::filesystem::path filesystemFileName() const`, but it's not available because `QT_FEATURE_cxx17_filesystem` is set to `-1` in `qtcore-config.h`. Why is that?

I'm using Qt 6.2.4 on MacOS Monterey with M1 Pro, but a x86_64 mac doesn't support this feature either.

Comment: Are you sure you are not compiling using Qt5?

Comment: I'm sure I'm using qt6

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling using C++17 or later?

Comment: yes, I `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)`

Comment: Odd. Have you set `QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.15` in your `.pro` file? Or perhaps even changed in `/usr/lib64/`(linux path, it's probably something else on your mac)`qt6/mkspecs/common/macx.conf` and set `QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.15` there (which would affect all projects)?

Comment: sorry for this late reply. I'm using cmake instead of qmake. And I definitely never changed those things.

Comment: Ok, but read about that. It's set to 10.14 by default and that wont let it use `std::filesystem`

Comment: I tried [set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.15)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET.html#variable:CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET) but it's not working. Is there extra steps I should watch out? And I wonder how this could affect `qtcore-config.h`

Comment: I don't know about that unfortunately. I have no Mac either so I can't test stuff myself. Perhaps you need to clone the Qt6 source, set `QT_FEATURE_cxx17_filesystem` to `1`  and build it from scratch as a last resort.